# Re-installing iTunes 12.2

Tags: itunes, downgrade

I am not happy with iTunes 12.3 (it constantly asks for my Apple ID) and I would like to re-install iTunes 12.2.

- Where can I find the 12.2 version?
- Will replacing 12.3 by 12.2 lose my music files and other personal data like rankings, subscribed podcasts, playlists, etc?

Comment: The solution by Tetsujin solves my problem. However I am still curious on whether it is easy/possible to go back to an earlier version of iTunes. The Apple website makes it easy to install the latest version but says nothing about older releases. I was a bit disappointed... So is "upgrading" a one-way road with Apple?

Comment: Apple likes to control its versioning. It doesn't ever want to be stuck in that hideous 'Windows XP' debacle where you cannot pry people of an ancient structure. You can generally on go back on anything if you still have the earlier installer on your hard drive - & not always even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download previous versions of iTunes directly from Apple. [This page here has a list](https://ipsw.me/iTunes) of available versions (and gives you direct links to Apple's content servers). The particular version you're wanting can be [downloaded here for Mac OS X](https://api.ipsw.me/v2.1/iTunes/osx/12.2.2/url/dl).

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be the epitome of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)…

Rather than go to all that effort, would it not be simpler to just set your password requirement to 'Never' ?

[image]